# Create To Do by code in vtiger crm

Tags: vtiger, vtigercrm

I am using vtiger crm version 6.4. We need to create some 'To Do' by custom workflow code. Now, the code we have, works for events, but not for ToDo. Can anyone Help me out with it? Added the code that is working for events.

```
$activity = Calendar_Record_Model::getCleanInstance('Calendar');
$activity->set('subject', 'Apply Offer Letter');
$activity->set('assigned_user_id', $assigned_user_id);
$activity->set('date_start', date('Y-m-d'));
$activity->set('time_start', convertToDBFormat($startTime));
$activity->set('time_end', convertToDBFormat($endTime));
$activity->set('due_date', date('Y-m-d'));
$activity->set('parent_id', $recordId);
$activity->set('contact_id', '');
$activity->set('taskstatus', 'LOF Received');
$activity->set('eventstatus', '');
$activity->set('taskpriority', '');
$activity->set('sendnotification', '');
$activity->set('activitytype', 'To Do');
$activity->set('visibility', '');
$activity->set('description', $description);
$activity->set('duration_hours', '0');
$activity->set('duration_minutes', '0');
$activity->set('location', $applicantLocation);
$activity->set('reminder', '');
$activity->save();
```

Answer (score 2):

Activity type should be "Task" instead of "To Do".

Change this line:

```
$activity->set('activitytype', 'To Do');
```

For this one:

```
$activity->set('activitytype', 'Task');
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, but it did not work for me. Made a different approach to create the entity and solved the problem.

Comment: Strange, I tested it and worked fine for me. But it's good to hear you could solve it differently. Cheers

Comment: This helped me get our CURL API going. Thanks.